# How do I display test statistic (F value) for anova using tbl_summary

Tags: r, statistics, anova, gtsummary

Here is the code that I am using to output a anova summary table with:

```
hiv %>% 
  select(education, sexfirsttime) %>% 
  mutate(education=
  factor(education, levels= c("no education", "primary","secondary","college"))) %>% 
  tbl_summary(missing="no", 
              by=education,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~"{mean} ({sd})", 
    label = sexfirsttime ~ "Age of first time sex") %>% 
  add_p(test= all_continuous() ~ "aov") %>% 
  modify_header(statistic ~ "**Test Statistic**")
```

*After executing the code, I get the following error message:
Error: Error in `update=` argument input. Select from ‘variable’, ‘test_name’, ‘var_type’, ‘var_label’, ‘row_type’, ‘label’, ‘stat_1’, ‘stat_2’, ‘stat_3’, ‘stat_4’, ‘test_result’, ‘p.value’*

When I try replacing `statistic` in modify_header with `test_result`, the output that I get a bizarre output as shown is in the image.

I am fairly new to using `gtsummary`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the most recent version of gtsummary and try again. In the most recent version, the handling of "aov" tests was made more consistent with the other tests, including returning the "statistic" column.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(grade, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = grade, 
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_p(all_continuous() ~ "aov") %>%
  # add a header (which also unhides a hidden column)
  modify_header(statistic ~ "**Test Statistic**") %>%
  # add a function to format the column
  modify_fmt_fun(statistic ~ style_sigfig)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>